# adding google maps autocomplete search box into a project built with sproutecore framework

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, sproutcore

I'm new to sproutecore framework, I noticed that things works pretty different than building a web app on pure javascript with jquery (for example)

Hence, I didn't understand how can I insert and bind a google maps searchbox view into my web app (in pure js it was just including the google api script and instantiating an object. something like that : `autocompleteDeparture = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(departureField, options);`
)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve exactly? Feel free to visit the iRC channel on freenode, or use Gitter (https://gitter.im/sproutcore/sproutcore)

Comment: I appreciate your will to help, however I found sproutcore a bit too complicated for me to learn now. I have an existing website and I mainly just want to get it's code cleaner and more "MVC-oriented". So I think that ["Knockout"](http://knockoutjs.com/) is a better solution for me right now

Comment: I can imagine, SproutCore is a full stack MVC app framework very much like a native GUI environment like Cocoa, and consequently requires a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

You typically put any outside JS files in a `frameworks` directory and then you can use it just like you included it in a `<script>` tag.

That said, you will probably want to execute your Google Maps code inside of the `SC.View`'s `didAppendToDocument()` method so that you are sure it is visible and the Google Maps code can properly bind to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
However, I decided to move into more easy-to-learn framework ("knockout" , to be specific), probably, sproutcore is a very powerful framework but it is very different from making site with pure HTML5-JavaScript-CSS-JQuery, I hope your answer will be useful for another people wondering in a similar case.